# Express-session cookie not saving in browser

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies, session-cookies

I've been researching this for hours now. What could be the reason why the cookies are not being saved in the browser? I'm using express-session. Below are the pieces of code I'm using.

```
const app = express();

// CORS config
app.use(cors({
  origin: process.env.API_URL,
  credentials: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}));

app.use(cookieParser());

// Where the sessions are stored
const MongoDBStore = new MongoDBSession({
  uri: process.env.MEDIRECORDS_URI,
  collection: "sessions"
})

app.set("trust proxy", 1);

const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

app.use(session({
  name: "irmp_session",
  secret: process.env.AWS_SESSION_KEY,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  maxAge: 7200000, // 2 hrs validity
  store: MongoDBStore,
   cookie: {
    path: '/',
    sameSite: false,
    secure: false,
    maxAge: oneDay
  }
}))
```

When I try to login using the frontend, the login is successful, the session is stored in the database. However, when I check the cookie storage, it is empty.

Answer (score 5):

After spending hours of researching, I learned that this is due to Chrome's cookie updates. [Here](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2020/01/get-ready-for-new-samesitenone-secure) is what the update is all about.

As the link states, for a cookie to be saved in Chrome and if it is really needed to set the `sameSite` to `none`, developers should set the `secure` option to be `true`. Default value of `sameSite` if not set is `lax`.

Hope this helps anyone who might encounter the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone here uses heroku or render.com for free, I added all the answers above but it is still not working. I have tried [another solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65767024/express-session-not-working-in-production-deployment/65767783#65767783) which is add `app.set("trust proxy", 1);` before `app.use(session(sessionSettings))` and it now saves cookie to different browsers.

Comment: Also found this when using Cloudflare tunnel :) thanks for the hint!

Comment: The solution you linked helped me after a week of trial and error. I'm using Render.com btw.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for sharing it. I was stack on this for 2 days now, in localhost things worked perfectly, but after deploy my MERN app in differents servers,  cookie  stoped working...

using express-session:

```
app.use(session({
   .......
   .......
    cookie:{
    maxAge: 24*60*60*1000, //please change it based on your needs
    secure: app.get('env') === 'production'?true:false,
    sameSite: 'none' 
}}));
```

this will solve the problem!!